# How to forward/handle WM_GESTURE message to a different window

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, touch

I am trying to send a `WM_GESTURE` message to a window application which handles messages inside `WndProc` callback, please see message sending below:

```
PostMessage(hWnd, WM_GESTURE, 0, 0);
```

`WM_GESTURE` message seems to be lost and never arrives to `WndProc` callback, also happens with `WM_POINTERUPDATE` message. Are there any way to handle both messages?

I will appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: `WM_GESTURE` need to be sent by the system to the application. `PostMessage` will return failure to post this message. Try to use [`InjectTouchInput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-injecttouchinput) to simulates touch input.

Comment: How can I simulate touch input from a different window? Are there any example using `InjectTouchInput`? Thanks for your help

Comment: The only reliable way to inject input is `SendInput` and `InjectTouchInput`. Neither one allows you to specify a receiving thread. The input goes to whichever thread is eligible to receive it, following normal input handling rules. With that it should be clear that your approach cannot work. Time to take a step back and let us know about the *problem* you are ultimately trying to solve.

Comment: I have 2 c++ window applications. Application1 has a transparent window which is always on top of Application2 window, which I am trying to do is when I perform a touch event in Application1, I need to forward this touch event to Application2 which handles WM_GESTURE in a WndProc callback function

Comment: Does Application1 window have extended window styles [`WS_EX_TRANSPARENT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/extended-window-styles)

Comment: @Drake Wu , yes, but it still does not work. I think that Application1 window should forward gesture messages to Application2 message loop independently of which window style is set on Application1

Comment: We've already established, that you only get *one* chance to handle `WM_GESTURE` messages. You cannot forward those messages, much like you [cannot forward keyboard messages](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513). You're going to have to scrap that idea and start working towards a solution. The solution here is to have the overlay window (Application1) become transparent to touch input. `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT` is part of the solution. See [this blog entry](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20121217-00/?p=5823) for details on this extended window style.